# insert date to oracle

Tags: c#, oracle10g

i have 2 **Date** field's in oracle 10g   (MyDate and MyTime)

and i need to insert **string** that contain a date & time

```
strDate = 04/01/2010 00:00:00

strTime = 01/06/2010 17:20:12
```

how to insert strDate & strTime to field's MyDate & MyTime

Comment: What is not clear about this question? Seems perfectly clear to me and Vincent's answer below seems to fit the question perfectly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

use the [`to_date`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions183.htm#i1003589) function to insert a date in Oracle (the Date datatype has both the "date" and "time" component in Oracle):

```
INSERT INTO your_table(MyDate, MyTime) VALUES (
   to_date('04/01/2010 00:00:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'),
   to_date('01/06/2010 17:20:12', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
);
```